# How to copy a response from one API post to another API post

Tags: api, postman, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

Using API requests, I'm trying to GET an execution result for a test (PASS/FAIL), and in some way copy that response and paste it into the request body (JSON) of a different API request that will POST that execution result (PASS/FAIL) some place else.

E.g.
This is the response I'm trying to copy
[execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEAe3.png)
And this is where I want to paste it
[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTJgd.png)

I tried looking around but I couldn't find anything regarding this scenario

Comment: It’s not clear what specific issue you’re having; it seems like standard JS object handling. [Please post the data as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/438992)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit as it it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve and how? Additionaly,
1. are you using Xray server/datacenter or cloud?
2. which endpoints are you calling and exactly with what content and what content is being returned?
3. what do you mean exactly by "some place else"?